# Auto fill a word document from line 1 in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, word

I have a list called `projectinfo` that I fill out at the start of a new project(sub-site) with Projectnumber, Contracter, Projectmanager, and so on. all in row one of the list.

When I create a new document in the site document library, I want the word document to be ready with all info filled out. I would like to do the same in Excel.
Is this possible?